# While using getContext from Facebook' MessengerExtensions I get an error

Tags: facebook, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I have a little problem with the implementation MessengerSDK in my react /preact app.

When using getContext I get an error

[Error from getContext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kzyne.png)

Code which caused it
https://gist.github.com/lordzfc/6765053c038b22542f17ab423909dd40

When I tested similar code on a static html website, it seems that everything works.

Is anybody who has a successful implementation MessengerSDK (for webview)

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask How you know this is the code causing it? From the image I can't guess.

Comment: I will update it